# Fragment being launched from FragmentActivity not showing up

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using the following code to launch a new fragment from a FragmentActivity:

```
PlaceholderFragment placeholderFragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
String TAG="TestFragment";
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFrag, TAG);
ft.addToBackStack(TAG);
ft.commit();
```

The Placeholderfragment:

```
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

For some reason, the "fragment_main" layout is not showing up.

I have debugged the flow and the etire code is executed but the screen stays at my FragmentActivity.
Anyone has any idea why this might happen? I have already wasted an hour without any clue.

Comment: try this way  FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentB, tag);

    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    ft.commit();

Comment: There might be a layout issue. Are you certain the layout of your `Activity` contains a view with the id `R.id.fragment_container` and are you sure that there is no issue with the layout `R.layout.fragment_main`? If you post both your `Activities` and `Fragments` layout we might be able to help you further.

Comment: @user3278732 what exactly is the purpose of your comment? He is already performing the `FragmentTransaction` correctly. And please don't post code like this in comments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Xaver Kapeller: You are right, it turned out the R.id.fragment_container was obscured by the parent linear_layout of the FragmentActivity as it had "fill_parent" specified.

Looks like my concepts of fragments are not very clear :P